# Clojure: how to enable spec asserts globally?

Tags: clojure, clojure.spec

I would like to use clojure specs to check the input of my functions (at least during development). So far, I have done the following: I have defined specs and at the beginnings of the functions I have put assertions like in this example:

```
(defn foo [bar]
  (s/assert ::bar bar)
  (do-something-with bar))
```

where `s` is an alias of `clojure.spec.alpha`. By default, these assertions seem to be disabled (when running unit tests with *midje*). I can enable them by putting `(s/check-asserts true)` into one of my files. I’m not sure what the scope of this setting will be then, though. It feels wrong to me to put it simply into one of the source files even though it seems to work for me so far.

What would be the recommended way to enable these assertions globally during testing but have them disabled when deploying the application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling this function is the correct way to globally enable specs. I would put it at the top of a global test helper file that's required by all of your tests if you want it globally enabled for all tests.

Answer (score 2):

There's also the system property `clojure.spec.check-asserts` which you can set to true. This is used to set the initial value for assertion checking.
See https://clojure.org/guides/spec#_using_spec_for_validation

Comment: How would I set such a system property? I wasn’t able to find any good information. Is this the same thing as a Java system property?

Comment: Yep, it's the same thing as standard java `-D` on command line.

Comment: I still don’t understand how I can set the system property when I run the tests with leiningen. Commands like `lein midje -Dclojure.spec.check-asserts=true` don’t seem to work.

Comment: Because leiningen normally runs two JVMs you need to specify it in project.clj. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32323572/is-there-a-way-to-set-system-properties-in-leinegen

Comment: And as mentioned before you can consider calling `check-asserts` function if you do this for tests. For example, we instrument all speced functions like this: `:profiles {:test { :injections [(require '[orchestra.spec.test :as stest]) (stest/instrument) (.println System/err "Instrumented specs")]}}`

Comment: I wasn’t able to enable the asserts with a system property, but calling `check-asserts` with an injection worked: `:injections [(require '[clojure.spec.alpha :as s]) (s/check-asserts true)]`

Answer (score 1):

To enable check-asserts globally using deps.edn you can add it to a profile. It is a jvm option.

In your **deps.edn** you can add this:

```
:aliases {:dev {:jvm-opts ["-Dclojure.spec.check-asserts=true"]}}
```